# Hibernate @SecondaryTable and @OrderBy

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an issue trying to sort a @OneToMany collection using an @OrderBy annotation when the target of the @OneToMany is an Entity mapped to multiple tables (using @SecondaryTable) and the sort property is in the secondary table.

A 'column not found' exception is thrown when trying to access the property as the generated SQL order by clause references the sort column using an alias to the primary table rather than the secondary table.

I cannot see anything I could add to make this work. Any thoughts?

```
public class Product{

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    // @OrderBy(value = "displaySequence")
    public Set<Benefit> getBenefits() {
    return benefits;
    }
}

public class Benefit{
    @Column(table = SECONDARY_TABLE_NAME, name = "display_sequence", nullable = false)
    public Integer getDisplaySequence() {
    return displaySequence;
    }
}
```

This is using the JPA @OrderBy annotation rather than the Hibernate specific.

Version of Hibernate is 3.6.9.

Within these classes everything is mapped using properties.

Other unrelated classes use mixed access mode

There is an existsing JIRA item which seems to demonstrate the same issue with an @Where clause:

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4246

The exception is a stanard SQL invalid column error.

The generated SQL is below. The 'order by' should reference display_sequence with reference to alias benefit0_.

```
select 
.....
from as_benefits_additional_data benefits0_ 
inner join as_benefits benefit1_ on benefits0_.id=benefit1_.id 
left outer join as_benefits_additional_data benefit1_1_ on benefit1_.id=benefit1_1_.id 
inner join as_products product2_ on benefit1_1_.product_id=product2_.id 
left outer join as_products_additional_data product2_1_ on product2_.id=product2_1_.id 
where benefits0_.product_id=1 
order by benefit1_.display_sequence asc
```

Comment: Could you give the exception message and stack trace? This sounds like a bug, but maybe something is missing from your example. Are you using Property access exclusively?

Comment: Which OrderBy annotation are you using?org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy or javax.persistence.OrderBy

Comment: Additional info appended above.